# MySQLi stmt num_rows returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having an issue with using `$stmt->num_rows` in PHP and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. `$stmt->num_rows` is returning 0 when it should be returning 1. The query *does* work and returns 1 result when executing it in phpMyAdmin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function get_login($username, $password)
{
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?";
    $stmt = $this->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $id;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You should realize that `num_rows` is *not needed* at all. You can make your code much simpler by either checking `$id` instead of `num_rows` (`return $id ?? false;`) or simply returning `$id` already, to pretty much the same effect (just `return $id;` will either return a number or `null` which in almost every context will be treated as `false`)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this, call the `get_result` first, then fetch the result.

```
public function get_id($username)
{
    $query = "SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?";
    $stmt = $this->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();          
    return $row['id'] ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Would you mind explaining why this needs to happen? To be completely honest with you, I don't really understand why I need to use store_result() here if I'm already fetching the result.

Comment: If you fetching the data first, it will increments the internal row counter